# rails send_data can't handle large file (2G+)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, large-files

My env:

- Mac: 10.12.4
- Memory: 16G
- ruby: 2.1.4
- rails: 3.2.22.5
- web server: thin 1.7.0

When the file size is under 2G, everything goes well.

```
class ItemListsController < ApplicationController
...
    send_data IO.read(zip_path), :type => 'application/zip',
        :disposition => 'attachment',
        :filename => file_name
```

However, when file size is larger than 2G, exception raised:

```
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ io_fread
```

I tried to use rubyzip to output stream instead:

```
    compressed_filestream = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zos|
      files.each do |file|
        zos.put_next_entry file[1]
        zos.write File.open(file[0], 'r').read
      end
    end

    compressed_filestream.rewind

    send_data compressed_filestream.read, :type => 'application/zip',
              :disposition => 'attachment',
              :filename => file_name
```

Exception raised with further detail:

```
Unexpected error while processing request: integer 2206004964 too big to convert to `int'
/Users/karl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@hcsvlab/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/connection.rb:328:in `send_data'
```

Seems send_data would read the whole file into memory then send data back.

My original plan is to find some way to provide "buffer" so send_data would read from buffer instead reading the whole file, but can't find such options in API

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `send_file` instead. According to the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Streaming/send_file):

> Sends the file, by default streaming it 4096 bytes at a time. This way
>   the whole file doesn’t need to be read into memory at once. This makes
>   it feasible to send even large files. You can optionally turn off
>   streaming and send the whole file at once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried to use send_file, but still doesn't work. The large file issue (larger than 2206004964 bytes) still exists. I tried different web server: Thin and Puma (3.8.2), still the same.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the new code with send_file?